# Projective representations of the Lorentz group can't occur in QFT! What's wrong with my argument?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, representation-theory, spinors, unitarity

In flat-space QFT, consider a spinor operator $\phi_i$, taken to lie at the origin. Given a Lorentz transformation $g$, we have
$$\tag{1} U(g)^\dagger \phi_i U(g) = D_{ij}(g)\phi_j$$
where $D_{ij}$ is some spinor projective representation of $SO^+(3,1)$, and $U$ is an infinite-dimensional unitary, perhaps projective, representation of $SO^+(3,1)$, satisfying
$$\tag{2} U(gh)= e^{i\alpha(g,h)}U(g)U(h)$$
for some real phases $\alpha(g,h)$. Now, using (1) and (2) we have:
\begin{align}
D_{ij}(gh)\phi_j &\stackrel{(1)}{=} \tag{3}U(gh)^\dagger\phi_iU(gh) \\ \tag{4}
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}e^{-i\alpha(g,h)}U(h)^\dagger U(g)^\dagger\phi_iU(g)U(h)e^{i\alpha(g,h)}\\ \tag{5}
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} U(h)^\dagger \big((D_{ik}(g)\phi_k\big)U(h)\\ \tag{6}
&\stackrel{(1)}{=} D_{ik}(g)D_{kj}(h)\phi_j.
\end{align}

Hence $$\tag{7} D_{ij}(gh) = D_{ik}(g)D_{kj}(h).$$ That is, $D$ is a true, non-projective, representation. Clearly this is false for spinors, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think (though I'm not sure) that "projective" just means (2): you allow a phase when acting on the Hilbert space, not on the Lorentz/spinor indices.

Comment: @Javier No, $D_{ij}$ is meant to be a spinor rep, so we need to allow a phase there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your observation is correct, which is why careful statements of the Wightman axiom eq. (1) (see e.g. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms#W2_(transformation_law_of_the_field)), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wightman+axioms#wightman_axioms)) stipulate that $D$ is a representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, the universal cover of the Lorentz group, not a representation of the Lorentz group itself.

Note that classical fields - the things on which $D$ acts - are not necessarily complex-valued, so the notion of a projective representation on them does not even make sense in general.